# Initialise array inside struct in C

Tags: c, compilation

I wants to initialise an array of struct variable, while the struct itself consists of array of bytes

```
struct my_bytes {
    u8 byte[128];
};

struct my_bytes data[] = {
    { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78 },
    { 0x13, 0x35, 0x57, 0x79 },
    { 0x14, 0x36, 0x58, 0x7a },
};
```

Compile is fine in native gcc 4.8.5 but error in other compiler/environment
Is there another way to initialise data?

Error message

```
it_sram.c:200:3: error: missing braces around initializer [-Werror=missing-braces]
it_sram.c:200:3: error: (near initialization for 'data[0].byte') [-Werror=missing-braces]
it_sram.c:199:18: error: unused variable 'data' [-Werror=unused-variable]
it_sram.c: At top level:
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-misleading-indentation" [-Werror]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: Is the comma after the last line of data intended?

Comment: yes. since data number is dynamic in size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed a level of {}

```
struct my_bytes data[] = {
  {{ 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78 } },
  {{ 0x13, 0x35, 0x57, 0x79 } },
  {{ 0x14, 0x36, 0x58, 0x7a } },
};
```

to have that more visible if I change the struct to be :

```
struct my_bytes {
  u8 byte[128];
  int a;
};
```

you need something like that :

```
struct my_bytes data[] = {
  {{ 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78 }, 1 },
  {{ 0x13, 0x35, 0x57, 0x79 }, 2 },
  {{ 0x14, 0x36, 0x58, 0x7a }, 3 },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need *two* pairs of curcly braces `{}`:

```
struct my_bytes data[] = {
    { { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78 } },
    { { 0x13, 0x35, 0x57, 0x79 } },
    { { 0x14, 0x36, 0x58, 0x7a } },
};
```

The outer is for the structure, the inner for the array.